# Augmented Reality Application Using React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, augmented-reality

Is there a way to add an AR module to react native application, I have tried Expo AR, but it seems to be deprecated. Also, Viro react seems to be not dependable at all. Anyone knows the solution to it